# How to extract objects from jQuery's $.get method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, callback

I am trying to return individual objects from a callback using jQuery's $.get method.

I can easily display the whole callback but can't pick individual objects from the method

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    $.get("http://domain.com/marketplace/api/v0/random_business_json/?callback=mycallback",
    function(data){
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
</script>
```

Here's the callback that is returned in my browser:

```
mycallback([{"pk": 6484, "model": "business.business", "fields": {"point": "POINT (-122.5447999999999951 45.7806700000000006)", "fax": "360-687-3148", "validated": true, "meta_description": null, "city": "Battle Ground", "mailing_zip_code": null, "mailing_address2": null, "state": "WA", "mailing_address1": null, "extension2": null, "extension1": null, "hours_text": "Opens Thursday\n at 8:30 a.m.", "latitude": "45.780670", "thumbnail": null, "zip_code": "98604", "website": "", "suggested_type": "", "description": "", "phone2": "", "address1": "713 West Main Street", "address2": "Suite 101", "phone1": "687-3149", "default_hours": null, "nickname": "", "slug": "boyd-james-m", "categories": [1218, 1227], "additional_hours_info": "", "business_type": 6, "name": "Boyd, Gaffney, Sowards, Mc Cray, Treosti, PLLC", "created": "2010-05-12 22:52:38", "safe_description": "", "notes": "Owner: STEVEN SOWARDS\n\nCONTACT_NAME: STEVEN SOWARDS\nTITLE_DESC: \n", "pre_name": "", "modified": "2010-05-12 22:52:48", "longitude": "-122.544800", "email": "", "mailing_state": null, "mailing_city": null}}])
```

I want to be able to pull pieces out like the pk,fields, ct etc...

I tried replacing **$('.result').html(data);** with **$('.result').html(data.pk);** to see if something like that would work but had no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` parameter to your success callback *is* an object if the response is JSON.  Trying to parse it as HTML doesn't make sense:

```
function(data) {
    alert("pk = " + data[0].pk);
}
```

Comment: This gives me an alert of pk = undefined

Comment: What do you get for `data.length`?

Comment: Seems like you're getting back a string, then.  Try adding a `dataType` argument to `$.get` specifying that the data is JSON.  Then you should get back an object instead.

Answer (score 0):

try `$('.result').html(data[0].pk);`

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.getJSON()` has JSONP support. This might be what you're looking for.

Use `?callback=?` in the URL instead of `?callback=mycallback` to get it working.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/